# How to parse table in a text file?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-files

I'm trying to scrape this page for the table of the holdings at the bottom, to get the information in each column: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1412093/000114036111027807/0001140361-11-027807.txt

What I have so far is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import datetime
import sys

def scrape(url):
    htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    tables =bs.find_all('table')
    for table in tables:
        print table

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1412093/000114036111027807/0001140361-11-027807.txt'
    scrape(url)
```

However, this only gets me the table, and I can't seem to further parse it going line by line.
Any help with this would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this is not an HTML table and rather a space delimited set of columns which you would have to parse differently. Here is a quite naive but working solution using `splitlines()` to split the table into rows and `split()` to split into columns:

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape(url):
    htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")

    data = bs.find('table').get_text().splitlines()[10:]
    for line in data:
        print([item for item in line.split()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1412093/000114036111027807/0001140361-11-027807.txt'
    scrape(url)
```

Prints:

```
['ADVENTRX', 'PHARMAMACEUTICALS', 'INC', 'COM', 'NEW', '00764X202', '289', '138,377', 'SH', 'SOLE', 'N/A', '138,377']
['AMGEN', 'INC', 'COM', '31162100', '54,519', '1,020,000', 'SH', 'SOLE', 'N/A', '1,020,000']
...
['SOUTHERN', 'UN', 'CO', 'NEW', 'COM', '844030106', '5,328', '186,154', 'SH', 'SOLE', 'N/A', '186,154']
['TAKE-TWO', 'INTERACTIVE', 'SOFTWAR', 'COM', '874054109', '151,310', '9,844,502', 'SH', 'SOLE', 'N/A', '9,844,502']
```

The most unreliable part is that `[10:]` slice. I'm leaving this for you to improve.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Is there anyway to split by columns? My concern with splitting on spaces is that some of the info like the company's name is split into multiple strings, and each company has a different length name. I see that there are <s> and <c> tags, but is it possible to split based on these tags? Or getting each column in separate lists?

Comment: You could do something like, look for the table, grab the dashes at the top of the columns. Count those and use that to split the rest of the data, strip white space from the beginning and end and you should end up with what you want.